# Using Tabris-js, and trying to use the cordova file and file-transfer plugins

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, tabris, tabris-js

Pretty new to tabris-js, however so far very impressed at the speed and ease of getting a native mobile app running.

I am playing with the camera function of cordova.. since there is a tabris-js example, that part is fine.  However, I am trying to utilise the File/File-Transfer plugins from cordova too..

Since you don't seem to import/include the cordova plugins (well, the ones in the examples), all I have done is use the cordova CLI to include the file/file-transfer plugins (adding them to my config.xml also).

Unfortunately, when I come to use say:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
```

to specify the file upload options (or indeed the var ft = new FileTransfer();), I get an error saying FileUploadOptions isn't defined.. this is when I am using the localhost tabris-js app by the way.

Any ideas on how (or even if??) to use the File/File-Transfer plugin??

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a restrictions regarding the file plugin right now. The Tabris.js team is working on it today.

Comment: Hi Holger, appreciate the rapid response!  I honestly think tabris-js shows real promise.. it has been the quickest framework/environment to get started building "real" native apps from JS.  I realise tabris-js is still beta/early (ish!) stages, but I can see some excellent benefits on the horizon, especially using existing cordova plugins.

Again, thanks for the reply, and excellent work for tabris-js !!